# How to setup implicit json convertion for spray+akka actor

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I'm Java developer and pretty new to scala.

I'm implementing some rest API that use spray and akka
The API should expose some kind of user CRUD. I'll use only create user in this question...

```
trait DefaultJsonFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with MetaMarshallers {}

class RegistrationService(registration: ActorRef)
   (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) 
                      extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats {
implicit val timeout = Timeout(2.seconds)
implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat3(User)
implicit val registerFormat = jsonFormat1(Register)
implicit val registeredFormat = jsonFormat1(Registered)

  val route =
    path("register") {
      post {  handleWith { ru: Register => (registration ? ru).mapTo[Registered] } }
}
```

//------ Actor

```
object RegistrationActor {
  case class User(id:String, name:String)
  case class Register(user: User)
  case class Registered(status: String)
  case object NotRegistered
}

class RegistrationActor(implDef: String) extends Actor {
 def receive: Receive = {
    case Register(user)=>
        val status=// create user real code with return status
        sender ! new Registered(status)
 } }
```

In this approach the json serialization and desiarelization is pretty annoying. For every object I need to deal with API I must define the appropriate format

```
implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat3(User)
implicit val registerFormat = jsonFormat1(Register)
implicit val registeredFormat = jsonFormat1(Registered)
```

I would like to avoid such definition and use some general json converter and return a pojo objects, so the conversion will happen under-the-hood

The question is how can I change this code to use by default Gson/Jackson/Spray default converter and avoid definition of the implicit ... jsonFormats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For every object I need to deal with API I must define the appropriate format

It is normal to do this once, in a "[JsonProtocol](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#jsonprotocol)" class and import that where needed, rather than defining new formats each time:

```
import MyJsonProtocol._

val route =
  path("register") {
    post {  handleWith { ru: Register => (registration ? ru).mapTo[Registered] } }
```

> how can I change this code to use by default Gson/Jackson/Spray default converter and avoid definition of the implicit ... jsonFormats?

You would need to declare an implicit marshaller from `Registered` to `HttpResponse` (or an intermediate value like `String`) which was backed by Jackson instead of `spray-json`, then import that marshaller instead of `SprayJsonSupport`.

Have a look at [the implementation of SprayJsonSupport](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/SprayJsonSupport.scala) to see how to do this. It's fairly straightforward, if you're comfortable with implicit conversions.

You can also see how this is done in [Json4sSupport](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/BaseJson4sSupport.scala#L16) in Spray -- that trait implements a `Marshaller[T, String]` for ALL types `T`. Then, at runtime, the `Json4s` library will try to serialize the object to JSON.

> In this approach the json serialization and desiarelization is pretty annoying

There are two main advantages of `spray-json`s approach over Jackson's:

- There is no reflection, so it is faster at runtime
- This is no runtime determining of JSON formats, so any issues are caught at compile-time

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into the example of JsonProtocol - and it does exactly the same I've done in question (like implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat3(User) ...) I've looked for a code version where the marshaling will happen automatically within handle_with{} block

Comment: "it does exactly the same" - yes, that's right; it's just more re-usable. "I've looked for a code version where" - I don't understand what you mean here. Let me know if I can clarify the answer for you.

Comment: I've seen the approach with Json4sSupport and the route definition like: pathPrefix("register") {  pathEnd { post {
          entity(as[Register]) { ru => requestContext => ...  In this approach the conversion happened withing --as-- operator and there were no need to define jsonFormat1(...) But I can't find a way to do such thing with handleWith

Comment: "In this approach the conversion happened withing --as-- operator and there were no need to define jsonFormat1(...)" -- yes, because Json4sSupport defines an implicit `Marshaller[T, String]` for ALL types `T`. You can do the same for Jackson, or just use Json4s if it meets your needs. The same marshaller can be used with "handleWith".